# How to avoid the " no left space on device " error , due to crystal reporty tmp log files

Tags: java, crystal-reports-2008

we are encountering a serious problem related the ".crtmp" temporary files of crystal report engine. 
In fact, this logs are very huge and  not cleaned up and cause this technical issue :" no left space on device ".

the code sample below is what we are using for report generation :

```
ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
    try {
        String chemin = (String) getSession().getAttribute(
                Constants.PATH_ETATS);
        reportClientDoc.setLocale(java.util.Locale.FRANCE);
        reportClientDoc.open(chemin + etat, 0);
        User u = (User) getSession().getAttribute(Constants.USER_KEY_BCT);
        Map<String, String> paramsDB = (Map<String, String>) getSession()
                .getAttribute(Constants.DB_PARAMS);
        params.put(Constants.PARAM_SCHEMA,
                paramsDB.get(Constants.TABLE_NAME_QUALIFIER));

        CRJavaHelper.switch_tables(reportClientDoc.getDatabaseController(),
                params, paramsDB);

        IStrings subreportNames = reportClientDoc.getSubreportController()
                .getSubreportNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < subreportNames.size(); i++) {
            ISubreportClientDocument subreportClientDoc = reportClientDoc
                    .getSubreportController().getSubreport(
                            subreportNames.getString(i));

            CRJavaHelper.switch_tables(
                    subreportClientDoc.getDatabaseController(), params,
                    paramsDB);
        }
        ParameterFieldController paramController = reportClientDoc
                .getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();

        paramController = setReportParameter(paramController, paramsReport,
                reportClientDoc);
        paramController.setCurrentValue("", Constants.PARAM_SCHEMA,
                paramsDB.get(Constants.TABLE_NAME_QUALIFIER));

        if (format.equals("txt")) {
            ICharacterSeparatedValuesExportFormatOptions csvOptions = (ICharacterSeparatedValuesExportFormatOptions) reportClientDoc
                    .getSavedExportOptions(ReportExportFormat.characterSeparatedValues);
            csvOptions.setDelimiter("");
            ExportOptions exportOptions = new ExportOptions();
            exportOptions
                    .setExportFormatType(ReportExportFormat.characterSeparatedValues);
            exportOptions.setFormatOptions(csvOptions);

            InputStream txtFile = reportClientDoc
                    .getPrintOutputController().export(exportOptions);

            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(txtFile);

            String str = openFileToString(bytes);
            System.out.println(str);
            String strFinale = str.toString().replace("endofline", "\r");
            strFinale = strFinale.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*$[\n\r]{1,}", "");

            System.out.println(strFinale);

            ByteArrayInputStream tmp = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    strFinale.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            writeToBrowser(tmp, getResponse(), "text/csv",
                    etat.replace("rpt", "txt"));
        } else {

            writeToBrowser(byteArrayInputStream, getResponse(),
                    TypeExport.getValeurMime(format),
                    etat.replace("rpt", format));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);

    } finally {
        if (reportClientDoc != null) {

            reportClientDoc.close();

        }
    }
```

Could you please tell me how to fix it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it a "no left space" or "no space left"?

Comment: Add some storage? Move the logs to a different volume?

Comment: we hope to find  a definite solution  by setting some crystal report parameters and/ or  calling a method from the java program (if it exists).